# When i am Trying to install JAVA 7 in Ubuntu 18.04 m facing some problem

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

**Package oracle-java7-installer is not available**, but is referred to by another package.
**This may mean that the package is missing**,that has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: Java 7 is end of life. That means the package is **obsolete**.

Comment: Any specific reason to stick to the old Java 7 ?

Comment: Java 7 is EOL, hence package is obsolete. Still, if you need JAVA 7 strictly for say some given problem you can always find Ubuntu 12|14 mirror list. or download .deb file and then install using dpkg.

Comment: Actually in my project there are some dependencies which is only avil in 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oracle-java7-installer`is no longer available from their `ppa:webupd8team/java` repository, and that would make sense now that Java 8 is out. Try installing Java 8 and see if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 22, 2019, it appears that oracle-java7-installer is no longer available from the ppa:webupd8team/java upstream repo (it could be that it got move to a different archive repo).

Alternatively, you can install oracle-java8-installer instead if you have the apt repo setup properly.

Previously its work with below steps-

Oracle JDK 6 and 7 are not available by default in Ubuntu 18.04/16.04 repositories and requires you to add repositories for the same as follows:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java (If you find upstream repo Update on this line and follw below steps)

$ sudo apt-get update

You may now run your command and enjoy using Java.

If you get error while installing ppa:repository, you will need to re-install ca certificates as follows:

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

Once this is done try running first two commands again.